# Допустимо ли использовать в прямой речи скобки?

Tags: пунктуация

Пример:
— Хорошим подспорьем здесь станет Центр опережающей подготовки (он будет действовать в рамках Межрегионального центра), —  рассказал директор.

Answer (score 1):

Да. Никаких ограничений на использование скобок в прямой речи нет. Возможно, лучше было бы поступить проще:
— Хорошим подспорьем здесь станет Центр опережающей подготовки, который будет действовать в рамках Межрегионального центра, — рассказал директор.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверена, что ограничений нет.

Дело в том, что предложение с прямой речью - это особая конструкция,состоящая из дословного высказывания и слов автора. Кроме того, после прямой речи может следовать описание действий героев  или авторские ремарки, заключенные в скобки.

Например: – Да, да, я знаю вас, Базаров, – повторила она. (За ней водилась привычка, свойственная многим провинциальным и московским дамам, – с первого дня знакомства звать мужчин по фамилии.) – Хотите сигару?

Поэтому скобки могут помешать корректному восприятию предложения.

Примечание. Да, после некоторых раздумий я всё больше склоняюсь к мысли, что скобки и прямая речь сочетаются не лучшим образом.

Попробуем рассмотреть три варианта текстов: длинный монолог героя в художественном произведении, дословную запись передачи и газетный репортаж с речевыми цитатами.

Но какой бы мы ни взяли вариант,  при оформлении прямой речи  можно использовать самые разнообразные средства для записи "лирических" отступлений от главной темы, а форма вставных конструкций для этого подходит меньше всего.

И уж тем более не подходят скобки, которые обычно используют для авторских вставок.

Comment: Я согласен, что без скобок лучше. Но было бы интересно разузнать точнее насчёт ограничений.

Comment: А что может помешать при воспроизведении устной речи поместить в кавычки длинное отступление оратора от темы очередного предложения? Другое дело, что в примере из вопроса в этом нет необходимости (проще точку поставить).

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это совсем в тему, но в школьных/вузовских сочинениях использование скобок ()/[] не приветствуется. Например:

> Она **[Маша]** была очень рада Мишиному приезду.

Использовать здесь уточнение в скобках учителя обычно не рекомендуют.

Это не значит, что использовать скобки неправильно. Вопрос об ограничениях.